# Asp.core custom props for jwt from external Autority scheme

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Could I change props in jwt, which I get from external scheme.

For example, could I set the expiration date or add a custom props into?

In code like this I cannot set something in `TokenValidationParameters` and validate this

```
services
  .AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
  .AddJwtBearer(options =>
  {
    options.Authority = "Some external authoriy link"
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
      {
        ...
      };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot directly change the properties  in a JWT token issued by an external provider. JWT tokens are digitally signed by the identity provider to ensure their integrity and prevent tampering. Any modification to the token's payload, including changing claims, would invalidate the signature and render the token invalid.